# Consuming SOAP web services in iOS application in Firemonkey

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I am new to iOS development with Delphi XE2 and Firemonkey and have a question how to consume SOAP web services from iOS application?

Is there any example for possible set of components involved to get the job done.

Thanks

Comment: Is iOS SOAP different from standard SOAP?

Comment: I think your ambiguous use of "from" needs clarification.  i.e. is it a service written in iOS that you want to consume, or are you writing an iOS client that needs to consume some other service?  I think you mean to say: "I am writing an iOS SOAP Client using Delphi XE2, and I need to know how to consume a SOAP web service."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is...
http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit

Unfortunately I did not discover this until I had written the whole thing using the cocoa platform!